# How to fit Lubuntu's panel in only one screen

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, panel

I have just installed Lubuntu and I am having problems with the panel. I have two screens, but the panel stretches through both ones. Is there a way to make it fit in only one screen, the main one? XRandR and ARandR does not help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on Lubuntu 18.04. I have faced this before and was again stumped today as I tried after a while. If you right click on the panel and select "Panel Settings", you will see dropdown list of options for "Monitor". You may select an individual monitor (1 or 2 in your case) or All which is what is default for you.

[image]

Comment: Earlier if I remember right, it used to be another dropdown choice in Preferences -> Monitor Settings. Opened a dialog called "Display Settings" wherein the choice was there.

Comment: Wow, it's been so long. And I left Lubuntu or the Linux world em general for some time already, hehehe. Thanks, I will mark this as correct one because it seems to be the case.